# Excel: contingent upon column, increment a different column and multiply all sums

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

So I have column A with mpnths. Column B has percent win and loss. I want to add 1 to the value in column B and then find the product of all values in column B to determine the compound growth of the dataset. Then I want to take this value and put in in my reports sheet.

=PRODUCT(SUM(1,IF(MONTH('#MOMO Trades'!A1:A1000)=4,'#MOMO Trades'!B:B,0)))

Please help me correct this formula.

thanks!

Comment: This isn't really important for answering your question, but I'm curious: why do you use `IF(MONTH('#MOMO Trades'!A1:A1000)=4,'#MOMO Trades'!B:B,0)` instead of just `'#MOMO Trades'!B:B`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a usable (textual) data sample and screenshot or text of your desired results. See Help for  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  To create a text example, take a look at this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), which will generate a delimited text sample you can paste into your question when you edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `SUM` function to add 1 to each row individually, you will need to use an array formula, rather than a formula. Otherwise, it will try to add 1 to an array, which it can't do.

To do this, enter the formula as you would normally, but when you have typed it press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will show up surrounded by braces, like this:

`{=PRODUCT(SUM(1,IF(MONTH('#MOMO Trades'!A1:A1000)=4,'#MOMO Trades'!B:B,0)))}`

Comment: What verson of Excel are you using that has the `ARRAYFORMULA` function.  I don't have it in mine (Excel for O365 MSO 32-bit).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld My bad, I used syntax from a different spreadsheet program. I'll fix it right now.